# Protect frontend form odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

What is the best solution for protection frontend form of spam, before insert data in database, random  addition two number or any captcha?

Any simple solution?

Comment: If you can share more about what form handling processes you are employing I can provide more detailed information.

Comment: HI, @user_odoo you can use Google Recaptcha before Posting the values. I have added such validations for a registration form on frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you are setting up your form however you should be able to do client side validation and server side validation. If the client side validation is not passed then Do not let the user submit.

Client side validation should always be followed by server side validation. In your controller or whatever process you are using to handle your form submission you can validate the data again. Use regular expression to validate phone numbers, email addresses, names whatever you wish to validate. Check that all required fields in fact contain data etc.

[HTML5 FORM VALIDATION](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/)

[Regular expression phone validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: Hi, I want that only human user can populate form on my frontend page and on bootom before click on Submit button add captcha or any other tools.

Comment: I have not implemented a captcha myself. However there are millions of them so my guess is that there is probably lots of code you can borrow to make it happen. Heres a howto I located. https://www.thesitewizard.com/general/add-captcha-to-feedback-form-script.shtml

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/adding-captcha-to-a-preexisting-contact-form/27914

Comment: A lot of this seems to be in PHP so you will need to port that to QWEB and python for Odoo.